# Activity Monitoring Toolbox missing from WSO2 BAM Server 2.4.0

Tags: wso2, toolbox, wso2-bam

The documentation of the WSO2 Business Activity Monitor version 2.4.0 refers to an Activity Monitoring Toolbox which is not present in my installation (default configuration on 64bit Linux with 64bit JVM v1.6.0_39).
Can I download and install the Activity Monitoring Toolbox from an external location?

Thanks,
Kai

Comment: you can check in this url: http://wso2.com/products/business-activity-monitor/toolboxes/ I see it there.

Comment: Thanks! The link refers to an old version (2.0.1) but it seems to be working (apart from a bug where the columns 'Activity ID' and 'Message Count' are swapped). The question remains though, what happened to version 2.4.0 of the Activity Monitoring Toolbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BAM 2.4.0 release onwards, the previous BAM activity monitoring components have been deprecated. They were replaced by a new implementation of activity search and monitoring with many more added features.

The following artifacts will no longer be shipped:

- With BAM distribution: the activity monitoring sample and the activity monitoring toolboxes.
- With BAM data agents: activity monitoring data agent which has so far been available under 'Service Data Publishing'

The newer activity search component has its own Jaggery app which can use to query data directly from Cassandra using indices rather than use Hive scripts for summarising data. It will also be shipped with the BAM distribution by default, thereby negating the need for installation of a dedicated toolbox.

The message tracer will replace the activity data publisher for dumping SOAP payloads to BAM. It will also serve in correlating messages based on ID.

Additional information can be found at: http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Activity+Monitoring+Dashboard

Comment: Thanks Inosh, I did notice the new Activity Monitoring Dashboard but unfortunately the documentation doesn't really explain much. At least I can stop hunting for the Activity Monitoring Toolbox now :)

Comment: I think you might need to take a look at [1] and [2] in order to understand how the activities can be monitored using Activity Monitoring Dashboard. Other important thing to note here is, events you are going to publish to BAM server should have an correlation parameter activity_id for correlate it to an activity.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Indexing+in+Cassandra
[2] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Searching+Cassandra+Data

Answer (score 0):

Activity Monitoring toolbox is packed and installed by default in the BAM 2.4.0 where you do not have to install is again. If you want to install it into a BAM 2.3.0 or an older version it will not be easy as the new Activity Monitoring toolbox in BAM 2.4.0 is not only dependent on the deployable artifacts, Stream definition, Analytic script and the dashboard. But it need some other jar files as well which is in the plugins.

Comment: Hi Maninda, I wouldn't ask this questions if the Activity Monitoring Toolbox was there. I have just re-installed the BAM Server to verify this and as before the Monitoring Toolbox is missing.

Comment: You are referring to the old Activity Monitoring toolbox. The new one is installed by default. You can verify by looking at the new dashboard in http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Activity+Monitoring+Dashboard